# Iterative patch generation for image segmentation - possible to optimise?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning

I am using CNN for voxel classification for segmentation of images. I am using a nested for loop to generate the patches used for the neural network but as the images I have are 3 dimensional, it's taking forever.

Is there anyway this can be optimised that I can't see?

```
def data_gen(image, labels, patch_size):

"""
:param image: 3 dimensional numpy matrix of image
:param labels: 3 dimensional numpy matrix of mask
:param patch_size: desried dimension of patch size
:return: array of patches and array of labels

"""

Patch_array = np.array([])
Label_array = np.array([])

PS = (patch_size - 1)/2

npad = ((PS, PS), (PS, PS), (PS,PS))

# Pad whole image with zeros to allow for patches at edges
image_pad = np.pad(image, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values = 0)

# Cycle over all voxels
for x in range(PS, image.shape[0]):
    for y in range(PS, image.shape[1]):
        for z in range(PS, image.shape[2]):

            # Add patch to array
            Patch_array = np.append(Patch_array, image_pad[x-PS:x+PS+1,y-PS:y+PS+1,z-PS:z+PS+1])

            Label_array = np.append(Label_array, labels[x,y,z])

return Label_array, Patch_array
```

Thanks!

Comment: As much as I love Python I think C++ is a better choice for this.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge : As mentioned in my answer - a C solution has already been build for this (via `numpy`)

Comment: My reaction was because your loops in the above example are in Python.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I am still working in python, but the solution provided by jmetz is in C compiled for use in python (numpy). Im unfortunately not (yet) a C++ user so this is best for now. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Scikit-Image utility function for this:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows

e.g.

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
window_shape = (patch_size, patch_size, patch_size)
patch_array = view_as_windows(A, window_shape)
```

Under the hood, this uses `as_strided` from `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give this a try, hopefully it will speed things up slightly!